# rviz with an existing point cloud

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I visualize an existing point cloud in rviz? I went through tutorials but it appears they use sensor data. I have a point cloud in bpf format and have tools to convert it to las format as well.

I am using ROS Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328670/rviz-with-an-existing-point-cloud/) by [tigershark](https://answers.ros.org/users/44070/tigershark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can convert it from a `las` to `pcd` using the `las2pcd` tool provided here: https://github.com/murtiad/las2pcd and then use the `pcd_to_pointcloud` node in `pcl_ros` to publish the pointcloud as (similar to https://answers.ros.org/question/62123/how-do-i-publish-pcd-files-in-my-folder-on-a-topic/)

```
rosrun pcl_ros pcd_to_pointcloud <file.pcd> [ <interval> ]
```

---

Originally posted by [nkhedekar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34897/nkhedekar/) with karma: 138 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2